# Azure Media Player displays caption names incorrectly

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I add two captions (English and Japanese) to the asset. However, the Azure Media Player shows caption names incorrectly. The caption popup showed **IMSC1** instead of English and Japanese.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw0ac.png

How I can show the caption names for English and Japanese correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this AMP https://azuremediaplayerdemo.azurewebsites.net to add the IMSC1 captions, but unfortunately it currently works for one caption.

[Img: Add language code for IMSC1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBlp0.png)
[Img: The caption popup shows the correct caption name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmri5.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use links to VTT text tracks as per https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/samples/dynamic_selectTextTrack.html

Edit: Sure, will relay your feedback to team, As of now (4/4/23) It is a known issue for Azure Media Player and only support one IMSC1 caption at the current stage.

But you could use the same way to add track and playback with players support multiple IMSC1 captions such as HLS.js.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Actually, I want to use IMSC1.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I'm late for the party but here is my solution:

1. The thing is when you add a text track - in this case: a VTT file, and set its player visibility to Visible. Then you create the stream locator with the policy StreamAndDownload. With this stream locator URL, the Azure Media Player will understand that this video is IMSC1 available, and it will:

- Align the close caption to the left (instead of center)
- The label in the setting is IMSC1 instead of Japanese or English

2. Solutions:

- Change the player visibility of both transcript track to hidden
- If your player loads the video dynamically, reference the template https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-media-player-samples/blob/master/html/dynamic_webvtt.html
- If your player loads the video from the video tag, reference the template https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-media-player-samples/blob/master/html/videotag_webvtt.html

3. Some of my personal thought:

- Based on this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/captions-text-track-concept#captions-vs-subtitles, you should only have one caption and multiple subtitles.
- If you init and configure the player with the video tag, you cannot init it dynamically (the reverse also true), so please consider your method carefully before implement it.